# dojo dynamically connect onclick event to drop down list item

Tags: javascript, dojo, event-handling

I have a search box sending ajax request to create a dropdown list of items from the JSON responseText. 
I want to link each item to an "onclick" event. However, using the code below, all my events happend at the same time (not even on click) once my dropdown list appears.

```
function getDropDownList(jso){
    if (jso.errorCode == 0){
        var result = document.createElement("div");
            result.className = "resultList";

        for (var i = 0 ; i < jso.resultats.length && i < 7; i++){
            var item           = document.createElement("div");
                item.className = "item";
                item.innerHTML = jso.results[i].name + ' (' + jso.results[i].localities + ')';

            result.appendChild(item);

            dojo.connect(item, 'onclick', myEventHandler);
        }
     myToolBar.appendChild(result);
     }
}
```

Can someone help me to figure out what's wrong with this scheme ?

Comment: I'm not understanding how you are creating the list of elements.  I seem to see that you are creating a set of <divs> attached to a parent <div> and then appending that div to something called myToolbar.

Comment: Yes, that's it. CSS make it look like a dropdown list just below my search box in my toolbar.

Comment: I guess what surprises me is that if you are leveraging Dojo, can you not simply use Dojo's own menu bar technology?  See the section called "MenuBars and More" at this page:

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/menus/

Comment: Well I am not used to Dojo yet. What I use is the Arcgis API for javascript built on the Dojo 1.6 framework. What i needed was a searchbox with an ajax suggestion list attached below. I couldn't find such a tool in the 1.6 documentation. The 1.6 documentation is kind of broken, many examples don't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use dojo/on and AMD load.

```
//this is a way
require(["dojo/query","dojo/domReady!"], function(query){
    //Use "dojo/request" if you need Send a request.
    var result  = dojo.create("div", {class:"resultList"}, null);
    //for()...... or import "dojo/_base/array" and make forEach
    query(dojo.create('div',
                    { innerHTML: jso.results[i].name + ' (' + jso.results[i].localities + ')',
                  class:"item"//other parameters here!.
                            }, null))
    .onclick(function(e){ console.log('clicked', e.target); })//or call myEventHandler
    .place(result);
    //End for
    query(result).place('#myToolBar');//add result to Dom element with id myToolBar
    });
```

More information on Dojo events can be found [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/events/).

Regards

Comment: Thanks, this made me found the answer. I just had to adapt your code with a dojo 1.6 syntax. In the end, using dojo.query(".item").connect was fine.